# Is it possible to make a new commit on the remote, that matches the contents of local repo, while maintaining history

Tags: git

My use case is a bit strange. I'm doing this programatically and don't have access to reset soft/mixed, and merge.

I have a repo on my local machine. I've made some file changes locally, but no commits. Someone else with access to the same repo has also made changes and pushed them to the remote. I want the file contents of my local directory to become the head of the remote. I basically want to force push, but maintain the existing history on the remote. An example should hopefully clarify:

```
Repo A:
    file1.txt
    file2.txt
Commits:
    "Init repo"
```

Both me and person 2 clone repo A. Person 2 makes some changes and pushes them. The remote repo now looks like this:

```
Repo A:
    file1.txt
    file3.txt
Commits:
    "add file3"
    "rm file2"
    "Init repo"
```

On my local repo I do some work. Now my local repo looks like this:

```
Repo A:
    file1.txt
    file2.txt
    fileA.txt
Commits:
    "Init repo"
```

I'd like to make a commit and push so that the remote looks like this:

```
Repo A:
    file1.txt
    file2.txt
    fileA.txt
Commits:
    "did my own thing"
    "add file3"
    "rm file2"
    "Init repo"
```

I just made a new commit where the file contents match my local directory exactly. I don't want to merge or anything like that. The important thing though is that the history is maintained.

Is this possible? I believe it can be done with a soft reset, but I don't have access to that. The other option is to clone repo A to another folder, delete the contents and copy over my local files. This would be too slow though. Is there any other way to do it?

Comment: You can use git pull -r It will place all your commits on top of all the commits.

Comment: That will fail if there are conflicts though.

Comment: @RamanSharma suggests the only possible solution. it should be the answer. `git pull --rebase` does the only possible thing git can do for you in this case. Have a look at https://serge.matveenko.ru/what-i-agree-with-is-that-rebasing-master-or-develop-branch-if-there-is-one-or-any-shared-branches-ea5c7e8b7f49
In case of a conflict nothing helps except manual resolution in any case.

Comment: Oh, I read that too quickly and missed the -r! @RamanSharma If you submit it as an answer i'll accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are asking for a strange thing to do, and probably should be using rebase instead (and I see you already accepted that as an answer).  But using rebase does not do the strange thing you asked for.

It's not possible to do this *as described and within these limitations*.  Moreover, the description you've given is misleading, because repositories don't contain files; repositories contain *commits*.  Commits then represent trees full of files, but until you tell Git to extract some *particular* commit, you just have a series of commits.

If you can relax your limitations, you *can* do it.  I'll describe how, and why, below.

#### What Git does

When you have two or more repositories, as is the case here, each repository has its own collection of commits, its own branch names like `master`, and its own notion of which is the "tip-most" (most recent, if you like) commit for each branch name.  In this particular case there are three separate repositories involved:

- the one at `origin`, which you are calling "repo A";
- yours;
- Person 2's.

You made the last of these by using `git clone` to have your computer call up another Git on `origin` and copy the entire repository—all of its commits—to your own.  Your Git took their branch names, such as `master`, and renamed them to *remote-tracking names* like `origin/master`.  Finally, your `git clone` ran `git checkout master`, which had your Git create your *own* master and set it to point to a commit by hash ID: the same hash ID they had listed for their `master`, which you are now calling `origin/master`.

This `git checkout` also filled in your *index* and your *work-tree*.  The index is where you will have your Git build your next commit—it's why in Git you are always having to run `git add`.  Your work-tree is where you actually see files.  They're associated with your own Git repository, but are not really part *of* the repository—unlike the index, which occupies a sort of shadowy place, halfway between commits (which are permanent and unchangeable) and the work-tree (which is where you do your work, and hence actually change things).

Person 2, of course, does the same `git clone`, which makes their copy of the repository, and then their `git checkout` creates their `master` and fills in *their* index and work-tree.

Now, there are a number of interesting things about the commits in any repository.  One is this "(mostly) permanent and (entirely) unchangeable" property.  Another is that each commit stores a snapshot of all the files that go with that commit—this is what gets you those files when you `git checkout` that particular commit.

One crucial, and rather magic, property is that every commit has a guaranteed-unique *hash ID* like `7668cbc60578f99a4c048f8f8f38787930b8147b`.  When I say *unique* I really mean *unique:* no matter how many copies of the repositories exist, `7668cbc60578f99a4c048f8f8f38787930b8147b` is the *same* commit in *every* copy.  It's either there, or not there, depending on whether you've picked up and saved it yet (if someone else made it), or made it yourself (if you are going to make it).

The final critical item is that every commit can store the hash ID of a previous or *parent* commit.  It's these hash IDs, plus the fact that a branch name like `master` stores the *most recent* one, that produces the history.  Git always starts with the most recent commit, by its hash ID as found under a branch name like `master`, and uses that.  Then, if you want to look back in history, Git finds that commit's parent ID, and looks at what files are in the parent commit.  The parent has another parent—the grandparent of the current commit—which has yet another set of files; and so on.

Whenever anyone, in any Git, makes a *new* commit, what Git does is save the *current* commit as the parent ID, and construct a new, unique (all over the world) hash ID for the new commit:

```
... <-hash  <-hash  <-tip   <-- master
```

becomes:

```
... <-hash  <-hash  <-old-tip  <-new-tip   <-- master
```

Since the hash IDs are unique everywhere, any Git can tell if it already has the commit(s) that some other Git has: if it's the *same* commit, the IDs match.

When you connect your Git to another Git, you have your Git ask them for their latest branches and so on.  They tell you their `master` is now some new hash.  Your Git can then ask their Git to send that commit, and its parent if necessary, and the grandparent and so on until you have the same commit.  Now you have all of your history *plus* any of their *new* history, without having to get all of their old history; and now you Git updates your `origin/master` to remember their new branch tip.

Or, you can have your Git *send* new commits to their Git.  But when you do that, your Git will ask their Git to set *their* `master` to the *same hash* as your own `master`.  So for that to work, you must first obtain all their *new* commits, and add your own *new* commits so that they come after theirs.

#### How you can use that

The above is the reason you normally would run `git fetch origin && git merge origin/master`, or `git fetch origin && git rebase origin/master`.  But that's not what you want to do, because that doesn't take your current *work-tree* and make that the *entire contents* of your new commit.

You want to totally ignore what Person 2 did in terms of *work*, while *keeping* what Person 2 did in terms of commit history.

This is a very strange thing to want, but it is what you say you want to do.

To get that commit history, you *must* `git fetch` the upstream commits.  If we label the commit hashes as single letters (instead of actual hash IDs), this is what you get:

```
...--E--F--G   <-- master (HEAD)
            \
             H   <-- origin/master
```

To now build a new commit using your work-tree, but build it atop Person 2's latest commit, you need `git reset --soft`.  This lets you move your current branch *name*, `master`, so that it points to the same commit as theirs, `origin/master`.  After `git reset --soft origin/master`, your repository contents—this does not account for your index and work-tree—look like:

```
...--E--F--G
            \
             H   <-- master (HEAD), origin/master
```

Your index and work-tree are *unchanged* because of the `--soft`.  You can now `git add -A` or similar to update your index from your work-tree, and `git commit`.  This will make a new commit `I` whose parent is `H`:

```
...--E--F--G   I   <-- master (HEAD)
            \ /
             H   <-- origin/master
```

and whose contents *completely ignore* what Person 2 did to make commit `H`, which is the strange thing you have asked for.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed response. You're right, what I want to do is strange and pull --rebase doesn't solve it. git reset --soft does work, but I don't have access to soft reset with the library i'm using. Is there ANY other way to do this that you could think of, or some more contrived way of doing a soft reset manually?

Comment: Well, `--soft` reset changes the *current* branch (reads `HEAD` to get the branch name, then does `git update-ref` on that name) without touching anything else (index+work-tree), so if you dive down a level, you can run `git update-ref refs/heads/<name> <newhash>` to get the same effect.

Answer (score 2):

Please do. It should work. I use it normally and it does rebase.

> git pull --rebase